# xpath: how to not match the following data

Tags: xpath

Viewing source, I have table data formatted exactly like this:

```
  <tr class="even">
    <td>apple</td>
    <td>pear</td>
    <td>orange</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
    <td>apple</td>
    <td>pear</td>
    <td>&nbsp</TD>
    </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td>apple</td>
    <td>pear</td>
    <td>orange</td>
    </tr>
```

How would I go about not matching the `<td>` containing &nbsp in all rows where it occurs?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and three complete one-liner XPath solutions. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entity `&nbsp;` isn't something that XPath knows about -- it is best to use its equivalent (self-defining) character entity `&#xA0;`

**To select all `td` s of a top element - `table`, that do not contain `&nbsp;` use**:

```
 /table/tr/td[not(contains(., '&#xA0;'))]
```

**To select all rows of this table such that none of their `td` children contains `&nbsp;` use**:

```
 /table/tr[not(td[contains(., '&#xA0;')])]
```

**To select all `td` children of all rows of this table such that none of their `td` children contains `&nbsp;` use**:

```
 /table/tr[not(td[contains(., '&#xA0;')])]/td
```

Comment: Good answer. Didn't know about `&#xA0;` ;)

Comment: @Oscar-Mederos: Yes, entities are processed and substituted *before* the XML document is parsed -- hence XPath (working on the XML Infoset -- the parsed result) doesn't know anything about entities.